# Lifetime troubles sharing references between threads

Tags: rust, lifetime

I've got a thread that launches worker threads, all are expected to live forever. Each worker thread maintains it's own list of `Socket`s.

Some operations require that I traverse all sockets currently alive, but I'm having trouble with lifetimes trying to create a master list of sockets containing a pointer to a socket owned by another list.

```
use std::{str, thread};
use std::thread::JoinHandle;
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::ops::DerefMut;
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender, Receiver, TryRecvError};
use self::socketlist::SocketList;
use self::mastersocketlist::MasterSocketList;

pub struct Socket {
    user: String,
    stream: TcpStream,
}

mod socketlist {
    use self::SocketList::{Node, End};
    use super::Socket;

    pub enum SocketList {
        Node(Socket, Box<SocketList>),
        End,
    }

    impl SocketList {
        pub fn new() -> SocketList {
            End
        }

        pub fn add(self, socket: Socket) -> SocketList {
            Node(socket, Box::new(self))
        }

        pub fn newest<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Result<&'a Socket, String> {
            match *self {
                Node(ref mut socket, ref mut next) => Ok(socket),
                End => Err("No socket available".to_string()),
            }
        }
    }
}

mod mastersocketlist {
    use self::MasterSocketList::{Node, End};
    use super::Socket;

    pub enum MasterSocketList<'a> {
        Node(Box<&'a Socket>, Box<MasterSocketList<'a>>),
        End,
    }

    impl<'a> MasterSocketList<'a> {
        pub fn new() -> MasterSocketList<'a> {
            End
        }

        pub fn add(self, socket: &'a Socket) -> MasterSocketList<'a> {
            MasterSocketList::Node(Box::new(&socket), Box::new(self))
        }
    }
}

pub struct SlotManager {
    prox: JoinHandle<()>,
    prox_tx: Sender<TcpStream>,
}

impl SlotManager {
    pub fn new() -> SlotManager {
        let (tx, rx): (Sender<TcpStream>, Receiver<TcpStream>) = channel();

        let tx_clone = tx.clone();
        let prox = thread::spawn(move || SlotManager::event_loop(tx, rx));

        SlotManager {
            prox: prox,
            prox_tx: tx_clone,
        }
    }

    pub fn sender(&self) -> Sender<TcpStream> {
        self.prox_tx.clone()
    }

    fn event_loop(tx: Sender<TcpStream>, rx: Receiver<TcpStream>) {
        let socket_list = Arc::new(Mutex::new(MasterSocketList::new()));
        let mut slot = Slot::new(socket_list.clone());
        loop {
            match rx.try_recv() {
                Ok(stream) => slot.new_connection(stream),
                Err(e) => {}
            }
        }
    }
}

pub struct Slot {
    prox: JoinHandle<()>,
    prox_tx: Sender<TcpStream>,
}

impl Slot {
    pub fn new(master_socket_list: Arc<Mutex<MasterSocketList>>) -> Slot {
        let (tx, rx): (Sender<TcpStream>, Receiver<TcpStream>) = channel();

        let tx_clone = tx.clone();
        let prox = thread::spawn(move || Slot::event_loop(tx, rx, master_socket_list));

        Slot {
            prox: prox,
            prox_tx: tx_clone,
        }
    }

    pub fn new_connection(&self, stream: TcpStream) {
        self.prox_tx.send(stream);
    }

    fn event_loop(tx: Sender<TcpStream>,
                  rx: Receiver<TcpStream>,
                  master_socket_list: Arc<Mutex<MasterSocketList>>) {

        let mut sockets = SocketList::new();
        loop {
            // Check for new connections
            match rx.try_recv() {
                Ok(stream) => {
                    let mut socket = Socket {
                        user: "default".to_string(),
                        stream: stream,
                    };
                    sockets = sockets.add(socket);

                    let mut msl_guard = match master_socket_list.lock() {
                        Ok(guard) => guard,
                        Err(poisoned) => poisoned.into_inner(),
                    };
                    let mut msl_handle = msl_guard.deref_mut();
                    *msl_handle = msl_handle.add(sockets.newest().unwrap());
                }
                Err(e) => {}
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut slot_manager = SlotManager::new();
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:1234").unwrap();
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(stream) => {
                let sender = slot_manager.sender();
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    sender.send(stream);
                    //process_new_connection(stream, sender)
                });
            }
            Err(e) => println!("Connection error: {}", e),
        }
    }
    drop(listener);
}
```

The errors that I receive...

```
error[E0477]: the type `[closure@src/main.rs:107:34: 107:86 tx:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::net::TcpStream>, rx:std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<std::net::TcpStream>, master_socket_list:std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<mastersocketlist::MasterSocketList<'_>>>]` does not fulfill the required lifetime
   --> src/main.rs:107:20
    |
107 |         let prox = thread::spawn(move || Slot::event_loop(tx, rx, master_socket_list));
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: type must outlive the static lifetime
```

I don't even know if what I am trying to is possible as safe code.

I wanting the `mastersocketlist` to contain a pointer to a socket where the socket's lifetime is defined by the thread that created it. I believe that's what all those errors mean, but I have no idea how to provide the proper lifetime annotations to fix it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A great thing about Rust is that the type-checking across functions is done solely by the function signature. That means you can replace most of the bodies of functions with `unimplemented!()` and preserve type-checking errors.

Repeat that process a few times, and you end up not calling a lot of functions - remove those. Inlining modules and reducing structs / enums can also help.

At some point your error will disappear - the first clue towards the problem! Keep at it, and you get a tiny reproduction:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

pub enum MasterSocketList<'a> {
    One(&'a u8),
}

pub struct Slot;

impl Slot {
    pub fn new<'a>(master_socket_list: Arc<Mutex<MasterSocketList<'a>>>) -> Slot {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            master_socket_list;
        });
        unimplemented!();
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Checking out the error, it still matches:

```
error[E0477]: the type `[closure@src/main.rs:12:23: 14:10 master_socket_list:std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<MasterSocketList<'a>>>]` does not fulfill the required lifetime
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: type must satisfy the static lifetime
```

Let's check the docs for the signature of [`thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html):

```
pub fn spawn<F, T>(f: F) -> JoinHandle<T>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> T,
    F: Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
```

The key point here is `F: Send + 'static` - the closure you give to `spawn` **must only contain references that last the entire life of the program**. This is because `spawn` can create threads that become *detached*. Once detached, the thread could live forever, so all references must live at least that long, otherwise you'd get *dangling references*, a bad thing! Rust saves the day, once again!

If you want to guarantee that the threads will terminate at a known point, you can use *scoped threads*, such as those provided by [scoped-threadpool](https://crates.io/crates/scoped_threadpool) or [crossbeam](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam).

If your code didn't have a variable with a lifetime inside of it, using some type of shared ownership like [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) paired with something that will ensure only one thread can mutate the variable, like [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) would have been sufficient. This allows each thread to own the shared value, finally dropping it whenever the last thread exits. See [How do I share a mutable object between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31373255/155423) for details.

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea I could slap `unimplemented()!` in there and make examples cleaner.  Thank you so much for the help!