# Cannot borrow data in an `Arc` as mutable

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I don't know what to do next. It looks like I misunderstand something, or maybe I have not learned some critical topic.

```
use std::sync::Arc;

use reqwest::{Error, Response}; // 0.11.4
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{self, Receiver, Sender}; // 1.9.0

pub struct Task {
    pub id: u32,
    pub url: String,
}
pub enum Message {
    Failure(Task, Error),
    Success(Task, Response),
}

struct State {
    client: reqwest::Client,
    res_tx: Sender<Message>,
    res_rx: Receiver<Message>,
}

pub struct Proxy {
    state: Arc<State>,
    max_rps: u16,
    max_pending: u16,
    id: u32,
    parent_tx: Sender<String>,
}

async fn send_msg<T>(tx: &Sender<T>, msg: T) {
    match tx.send(msg).await {
        Err(error) => {
            eprintln!("{}", error)
        }
        _ => (),
    };
}

impl Proxy {
    // Starts loop for input channel
    async fn start_chin(&mut self) -> Sender<Task> {
        let (chin_tx, mut chin_rx) = mpsc::channel::<Task>(self.max_pending as usize + 1 as usize);
        let state_outer = self.state.clone();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            loop {
                match chin_rx.recv().await {
                    Some(task) => {
                        let res_tx = state_outer.res_tx.clone();
                        let state = state_outer.clone();
                        tokio::spawn(async move {
                            match state.client.get(&task.url).send().await {
                                Ok(res) => send_msg(&res_tx, Message::Success(task, res)).await,
                                Err(err) => send_msg(&res_tx, Message::Failure(task, err)).await,
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    None => (),
                }
            }
        });
        chin_tx
    }

    async fn start_chres(&self) {
        let state = self.state.clone();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            loop {
                match state.res_rx.recv().await { // LINE PRODUCES ERROR
                    Some(task) => {}
                    None => (),
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

impl Proxy {
    pub fn new(
        id: u32,
        parent_tx: Sender<String>,
        proxy_addr: &str,
        max_rps: u16,
        max_pending: u16,
    ) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let client = reqwest::Client::builder();
        if proxy_addr != "none" {
            client = client.proxy(reqwest::Proxy::all(proxy_addr)?)
        }
        let (res_tx, res_rx) = mpsc::channel::<Message>(max_pending as usize + 1 as usize); // TODO: check size

        Ok(Proxy {
            id,
            state: Arc::new(State {
                client: client.build()?,
                res_tx,
                res_rx,
            }),
            max_rps,
            max_pending,
            parent_tx,
        })
    }
}
```

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in an `Arc` as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:69:23
   |
69 |                 match state.res_rx.recv().await {
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |
   = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Arc<State>`
```

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I share a mutable object between threads using Arc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31373255/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: From the [documentation of `Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), emphasis mine: *Shared references in Rust disallow mutation by default, and `Arc` is no exception: you cannot generally obtain a mutable reference to something inside an `Arc`. **If you need to mutate through an `Arc`, use `Mutex`, `RwLock`, or one of the `Atomic` types**.*

Comment: See also [`tokio::sync::Mutex`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.9.0/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I share a mutable object between threads using Arc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373255/how-do-i-share-a-mutable-object-between-threads-using-arc)

Comment: A single consumer channel can only have a single consumer, so the `res_rx` should be owned by the task and not be shared behind an `Arc`.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, yesterday was a hard day. I meant the following: how can I avoid this situation in the most optimal way. Each link helped me understand the big picture and I came up with a great solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucas Zanella's answer and Shepmaster's comments helped alot to refactor and simplify code. I've desided to pass ownership inside `Proxy::new()` function instead of using shared reference. The code became more readable, and I've avoided shared reference for mutable `tokio::sync::mpsc::Receiver`. Perhaps the question turned out to be too unstructured, but I came to a new approach thanks to the community. Refactored code is listed below.

```
use reqwest::{Client, Error, Response};
use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{Sender, Receiver};


pub struct Task {
    pub id: u32,
    pub url:  String,
}
pub enum Message{
    Failure(Task, Error),
    Success(Task, Response),
}
pub struct Proxy{
    id: u32,
    max_rps: u16,
    max_pending: u16,
    in_tx: Sender<Task>,
}


async fn send_msg<T>(tx: &Sender<T>, msg: T){
    match tx.send(msg).await {
        Err(error) => { eprintln!("{}", error) },
        _ => (),
    };
}


async fn start_loop_in(client: Client, mut in_rx: Receiver<Task>, res_tx: Sender<Message>){
    loop {
        if let Some(task) = in_rx.recv().await {
            let client_clone = client.clone();
            let res_tx_clone = res_tx.clone();
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                println!("SENDING: {}", &task.url); // TODO: DELETE DEBUG
                match client_clone.get(&task.url).send().await {
                    Ok(res) => send_msg(&res_tx_clone, Message::Success(task, res)).await,
                    Err(err) => send_msg(&res_tx_clone, Message::Failure(task, err)).await,
                }
            });
        }
    }
}


async fn start_loop_res(mut res_rx: Receiver<Message>, out_tx: Sender<String>){
    loop {
        if let Some(message) = res_rx.recv().await {
            match message {
                Message::Success(task, res) => { 
                    send_msg(
                        &out_tx, 
                        format!("{:#?}", res.text().await.unwrap()) // TODO: change in release!
                    ).await;
                },
                Message::Failure(task, err) => {
                    send_msg(&out_tx, err.to_string()).await;
                },
            }
        }
    }
}


impl Proxy{

    pub fn new(id: u32, parent_tx: Sender<String>, proxy_addr: &str, max_rps: u16, max_pending: u16) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        
        let mut client = Client::builder();
        if proxy_addr != "none" { client = client.proxy(reqwest::Proxy::all(proxy_addr)?) }
        let (res_tx, res_rx) = mpsc::channel::<Message>(max_pending as usize + 1 as usize); // TODO: check size

        let client = client.build()?;
        let (in_tx, in_rx) = mpsc::channel::<Task>(max_pending as usize + 1 as usize);
        let res_tx_clone = res_tx.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move { start_loop_in(client, in_rx, res_tx_clone).await });

        tokio::spawn(async move { start_loop_res(res_rx, parent_tx).await });
        
        Ok(Proxy{
            id,
            max_rps,
            max_pending,
            in_tx,
        })
    }

    pub fn get_in_tx(&self) -> Sender<Task> {
        self.in_tx.clone()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

```
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Something {
    size: usize
}

impl Something {
    fn increase(&mut self) {
        self.size = self.size + 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let something = Something{size: 1};
    let arc = Arc::new(something);
    arc.increase();
}
```

gives

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in an `Arc` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:16:5
   |
16 |     arc.increase();
   |     ^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |
   = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Arc<Something>`

error: aborting due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

because it tries to borrow `arc` as mutable. For it to happen, `DerefMut` would have to be implemented for `Arc` but it's not because `Arc` is not meant to be mutable.

Wraping your object in a `Mutex` works:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

struct Something {
    size: usize
}

impl Something {
    fn increase(&mut self) {
        self.size = self.size + 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let something = Something{size: 1};
    let arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(something));
    arc.lock().unwrap().increase();
}
```

Now it can be shared and can be increased.

Comment: The question asks how to do this, but in context where it shouldn't have been attempted in the first place.

Comment: Better not use `std::sync::Mutex` for async applications as it will block whole system thread causing programm deadlock. If you use `tokio` then it will be better to use `tokio::sync::Mutex` - it doesn't block system thread.

Comment: According [this](https://github.com/actix/actix-website/issues/201) the Actix team recommends using the standard library mutex.

Comment: Locking a `tokio::sync::Mutex` is more expensive than a `std::sync::Mutex`. If you don't actually need to hold the lock across `.await`s then you should use the one from `std`, or even better, `parking_lot::Mutex`.