# Rust using moved value in Thread

Tags: multithreading, rust

My code is like:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashSet, thread};

pub fn handle_server(blacklisted: Vec<String>) -> Vec<String> {
    return blacklisted;
}

pub fn handle_client() {
    return;
}

fn main() {
    let mut blacklisted = Vec::new();
    let ip_address_clone = ["100".to_string(), "200".to_string(), "300".to_string()];
    let self_ip = "100".to_string();

    for _ip in ip_address_clone.clone()
    //LEADER SENDS TO EVERY IP
    {
        if !blacklisted.clone().contains(&self_ip.clone()) {
            let mut blacklisted_clone = blacklisted.clone();

            let handle1 = thread::spawn(move || {
                let mut blacklisted_child = handle_server(blacklisted_clone.clone());

                blacklisted_clone.append(&mut blacklisted_child);

                let set: HashSet<_> = blacklisted_clone.drain(..).collect();

                blacklisted_clone.extend(set.into_iter());
            });
            blacklisted = blacklisted_clone;

            let handle2 = thread::spawn(move || {
                handle_client();
            });

            handle1.join().unwrap();
            handle2.join().unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `blacklisted_clone`
  --> src/main.rs:31:27
   |
20 |             let mut blacklisted_clone = blacklisted.clone();
   |                 --------------------- move occurs because `blacklisted_clone` has type `Vec<String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
21 |
22 |             let handle1 = thread::spawn(move || {
   |                                         ------- value moved into closure here
23 |                 let mut blacklisted_child = handle_server(blacklisted_clone.clone());
   |                                                           ----------------- variable moved due to use in closure
...
31 |             blacklisted = blacklisted_clone;
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

As you can see, I am blacklisting some ip addresses based on return from
`handle_server()`.

I am updating `blacklisted` within the thread move, and also I am trying to access its value in the if statement in the line just below the loop.
Therefore, I am trying to use a clone of `blacklisted` (to avoid using moved value). But in the line `blacklisted = blacklisted_clone;` I am updating the `blacklisted` with `blacklisted_clone`. Here I am getting `use of moved value:` blacklisted_clone `error.`

What should be my procedure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I share a mutable object between threads using Arc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373255/how-do-i-share-a-mutable-object-between-threads-using-arc)

Comment: I think a combination of sharing a reference via [scoped threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750829/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-stack-variable-to-a-thread/32751956#32751956) and a [`Mutex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373255/how-do-i-share-a-mutable-object-between-threads-using-arc) will work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of things wrong with your code. I'll structure this answer in two parts.

- Fix the unrelated problems I can see, because without fixing them the fix for the `moved value` error would be very confusing
- Solve the actual `moved value` error

Those are the things I will fix before talking about your actual question:

- There is no reason to create `blacklisted_clone`. It simply makes the entire problem more confusing. Simply use the original `blacklisted` object.
- It's very confusing (and slow) that you repeatedly move data back and forth between different datastructures. Don't use a `Vec` and a `HashSet` back and forth. Choose one and keep that. In your case, I would choose a `HashSet`, as your elements seem to be unique.
- Don't pass an owned object to `handle_server`, as it will copy the blacklist yet again. Use a reference instead. Also, don't do `.clone()` whenever it suits you - try to use references. `.clone()` duplicates the entire data, so it is quite slow.

With those all fixed, the code would now look like this:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashSet, thread};

pub fn handle_server(ip: &str, _blacklisted: &HashSet<String>) -> Vec<String> {
    return vec![format!("{ip}_blacklisted")];
}

pub fn handle_client() {
    return;
}

fn main() {
    let mut blacklisted = HashSet::new();
    let ip_address_clone = ["100".to_string(), "200".to_string(), "300".to_string()];
    let self_ip = "100".to_string();

    for ip in ip_address_clone.clone()
    //LEADER SENDS TO EVERY IP
    {
        if !blacklisted.contains(&self_ip.clone()) {
            let handle1 = thread::spawn(move || {
                let blacklisted_child = handle_server(&ip, &blacklisted);
                // I assume `blacklisted_child` will contain new items that should get blacklisted,
                // and that need to be added to the original `blacklisted` object.
                blacklisted.extend(blacklisted_child);
            });

            let handle2 = thread::spawn(|| {
                handle_client();
            });

            handle1.join().unwrap();
            handle2.join().unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `blacklisted`
  --> src\main.rs:19:13
   |
12 |     let mut blacklisted = HashSet::new();
   |         --------------- move occurs because `blacklisted` has type `HashSet<String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
19 |         if !blacklisted.contains(&self_ip.clone()) {
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
20 |             let handle1 = thread::spawn(move || {
   |                                         ------- value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop
```

---

Now let's fix the original problem of `value moved`.

It appears because threads are not guaranteed to terminate at a given point; in this case, it is especially not guaranteed that `main()` outlives the thread. Therefore the thread cannot use anything that lives in `main()` (because `main()` could terminate while the thread still uses the data), and Rust forces you to make the closure a `move ||` closure that moves the used items **into** the closure.

Sadly, moving values into a closure removes them from `main()`, which causes the errors you are seeing.

There are multiple ways to fix this, especially `Arc` and *scoped threads*.

In the past, mostly `Arc` was used and you will almost exclusively find `Arc` in previous answers. The reason is that scoped threads are fairly new. That said, they exist to fix your exact problem.

It basically means that you define a `std::thread::scope` around the thread, and Rust now understands how long the thread can maximally live. Threads spawned inside that scope will also automatically be joined at its end, so no explicit `join` is necessary.

And like that, it just simply works:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashSet, thread};

pub fn handle_server(ip: &str, blacklisted: &HashSet<String>) -> Vec<String> {
    println!("Handling {ip:?}. Already blacklisted: {blacklisted:?}");
    return vec![format!("{ip}_blacklisted")];
}

pub fn handle_client() {
    return;
}

fn main() {
    let mut blacklisted = HashSet::new();
    let ip_address_clone = ["100".to_string(), "200".to_string(), "300".to_string()];
    let self_ip = "100".to_string();

    for ip in ip_address_clone.clone()
    //LEADER SENDS TO EVERY IP
    {
        if !blacklisted.contains(&self_ip.clone()) {
            thread::scope(|s| {
                s.spawn(|| {
                    let blacklisted_child = handle_server(&ip, &blacklisted);
                    // I assume `blacklisted_child` will return new items that should get blacklisted,
                    // and that need to be added to the original `blacklisted` object.
                    blacklisted.extend(blacklisted_child);
                });

                s.spawn(|| {
                    handle_client();
                });
            })
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", blacklisted);
}
```

```
Handling "100". Already blacklisted: {}
Handling "200". Already blacklisted: {"100_blacklisted"}
Handling "300". Already blacklisted: {"200_blacklisted", "100_blacklisted"}
{"200_blacklisted", "300_blacklisted", "100_blacklisted"}
```

---

Extra note:

In this case this only works because only one thread is using `blacklisted` simultaneously. If you would use it inside multiple threads, you would get an error that only one `&mut` reference can exist at a given time. In that case, you would need to use `&` references and interior mutability via `Mutex`. I won't go into detail here, though, as it isn't necessary in your case, but just wanted to mention it so you have heard of it already.