# Rust: Cannot borrow data in `Arc` as mutable, but inner data is protected via Mutex

Tags: rust, mutex, automatic-ref-counting

While learning Rust, and trying to work through an example wherein a database `Db` is required to be shared across threads and functions.

[**Link To Minimal Example**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=111d8c51820ad28f7fe04c33b79ac475)

I have wrapped the database (a struct) in an `Arc`, and within the struct, protected the member with a `Mutex`:

```rust
pub struct Db{
    pub db: Mutex<BTreeMap<String, String>>,
}
```

However, I get the error when attempting to update `Db` via an associated method:

> help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Arc<Db>`

I have seen [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373255/how-do-i-share-a-mutable-object-between-threads-using-arc), but instead of `Arc::new(Mutex::new(Db))`, I only pass `Arc::new(Db)` with the understanding that inner member of the database is mutex-protected.

**Question** How do I indicate to the compiler that inner data member of `Db` is access protected in order to successfully build [**Link To Minimal Example**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=111d8c51820ad28f7fe04c33b79ac475) ? If this were possible, would this be a recommended approach?

**Other Information**
`rustc 1.65.0 (897e37553 2022-11-02)`

Comment: Well you need to `lock()`. Also, why do you use `try_lock()`?

Comment: In the future, please embed your entire minimal example code into your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the [mre] *within* the question, only posting a link is not enough for various reasons amongst them is that the offline dumps of these questions are practically useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you have

```rust
impl Db {
    pub fn add(&mut self, data: String) -> Option<String> { ... }
}
```

But, as you said, you protect the database inside a `Mutex`. So you don't need `mut` access:

```rust
impl Db {
    pub fn add(&self, data: String) -> Option<String> { ... }
}
```

See, `&mut` in Rust really means "exclusive" or "unique" access. Rust will enforce that `&mut` references are unique at compile time, which is why it gives you that error. `Mutex` only requires a "shared" (immutable) `&` reference, and enforces the same rules at runtime instead.

Removing that `mut` is literally all that's necessary to make [your example work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=68dbbb8ecb26508e91e7d2596c7ff810)